# GPServer does not exist or is inaccessible

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, geoprocessing-service

I have successfully published a Geoprocessing Tool as GP services, I had called it with success, but when I try to call it, now it gives me this error `GPServer does not exist or is inaccessible` for no reason. MapServer and GeocodeServer work fine I am having a problem just with the GPServer.

Comment: I am having the same issues, did you ever find a solution to this problem. GPService runs a fews times and then fails and says data does not exist or is not supported. It is acting like it can not read a table in Oracle, connection issue. But cant track down the issue.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  You have posted what should be a comment into the area reserved for direct answers to the question posed so I will convert it to a comment.  I encourage you to ask/answer a few questions here in order to build enough reputation to gain the [comment everywhere privilege](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).